# DevExpress Gridview MVC : where do you place events of the gridview?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, events, model, devexpress

I am working on a MVC project using a gridview of DevExpress .

I am new to MVC and DevExpress .

In the project for each kind of gridview :
- i have a model which gives access to database and returns lists of datas
-I have a controller which passes the model to the concerned view.
-I have a gridview which displays and sorts the datas of the bound model.
The gridview requires several events to display properly datas of unbound columns, to display combobox filter rows, etc....

I use coding to define the gridview (i dont know if i am doing right or wrong,can you confirm?)

Its like :

```
GridViewSettings settings = new GridViewSettings();
settings.Name = "grid";
....
  //this event to strike the disabled objects in the grid
settings.HtmlRowPrepared = ((project.Models.theModel)Model).gridUsers_htmlRowPrepared;
.....
//And now i render the gridview and i bind it to the list of objects
     Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings). Bind(((project.Models.theModel)Model).getListOfObjects()).Render();
```

As you can see, for the moment , my events are placed in the model .

MVC's way is to separate data process from views.

My models store the methods for fixing the display of my gridviews : that doesnot sound MVC at all .

How do you manage your events? where do you place them?

Bear in mind that , in the project, i can access the objets of database only from the model (thats why i put the events in the model, to make it easier ).

Thanks in advance for answers... Gridview MVC is a challenge for me.

Answer (score 0):

İf i did not get you wrong , İ added a GridView Example,

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "gvFilterRow";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "GridView", Action = "FilterRowPartial" };
    settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

    settings.Columns.Add("ProductName");
    settings.Columns.Add(column => {
        column.FieldName = "CategoryID";
        column.Caption = "Category";

        column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
        var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
        comboBoxProperties.DataSource = NorthwindDataProvider.GetCategories();
        comboBoxProperties.TextField = "CategoryName";
        comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "CategoryID";
        comboBoxProperties.ValueType = typeof(int);
        comboBoxProperties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDown;
    });


    settings.Columns.Add("QuantityPerUnit");
    settings.Columns.Add("UnitPrice").PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = "c";
    settings.Columns.Add("ReorderLevel");
    settings.Columns.Add("Discontinued", MVCxGridViewColumnType.CheckBox);

    settings.Settings.ShowFilterRow = true;
    settings.Settings.ShowFilterRowMenu = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.ClearFilterButton.Visible = true;
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Comment: Hello dear user2791307 . Unfortunately i can't see you managing events in your gridview example. Events are like "HtmlRowPrepared" or "RowValidating" or "CustomUnboundColumnData" . These events need methods : where do you place these methods? From where do you call them ?